# Deleted NTFS partition to ext4 conversion

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs, ext4

I have deleted NTFS drive in Windows. After I have added it in Linux I did a quick format to Ext4 (`sda9`), but it says that 12 GB or (2% of the drive capacity) is used.

Is this normal? Or should I do a full format? Also moving from NTFS to Ext4 is it recommended to do a full format (although quick format seems to be working), does it improves efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

The space is probably taken by [reserved blocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19504/reasonable-size-for-filesystem-reserved-blocks-for-non-os-disks), which is usually set to 5%. You can check with `tune2fs`, assuming /dev/sda1 is the right partition.

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'block count
```

To set the percentage of reserved block to, say, 1%, use the following:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1
```

Comment: I checked it. It's exactly 5%. But my used space is about 2%