# Why does the home folder eats few gigabytes(say 6gb) of its allocated space where that space lies and used for what?

Tags: filesystem, gparted, disk-usage, user-space

Recently i installed timeshift for backup system recovery....it ate up half of the drive and i decided to uninstall timeshift.... and i decided to clean up the system as well by referring to some sites.... after a full cleaning i checked the gparted application for free space details... it showed me 65.7 GB FREE... BUT THE ORIGINAL SPACE I ALLOCATED WAS 70 GB for home folder.... where is that remaining 4.3 gigs of space?? i checked all folders but there is no additional file.... how come it occupied 4.3 gigs of space without my concent, is that a virus in my pc, i recently checked web about the ubuntu system installation files which are installed only in /(root) folder.....

Comment: Perhaps the difference is due to rounding.  Sometimes, they define a kb as 1,000 bytes; other times, it is 1,024 bytes.  When you multiply it out, it makes a difference.  I think if you look at a HDD box, you will notice (well, at least the boxes I've seen) that they use 1,000 bytes.  If Ubuntu uses 1,024 bytes (and it usually does), you see a big difference.  i.e. A HDD with 14 TB on the box actually has 12 TB when it's read by Ubuntu.  This happened to me recently...

Comment: OH I SEE.... Is that a bug, is there a way i can fix it???? If so thanks in advance

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/19504/reasonable-size-for-filesystem-reserved-blocks-for-non-os-disks for another way disk space may become unavailable to you.The system reserves some (5% default) for itself.

Comment: You can also look at this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) on Wikipedia for a detailed explanation.  The section "Inconsistent use of units" is quite well written.  But as @ubfan1 says, the system may also reserve space.  Either way, there's no way to "get more space", so I wouldn't dwell on it for too long.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate Hard Drive Size in Bytes
Two different mathematical systems are used to define how much information can be stored on the hard disk drive of your computer: binary or base-2 mathematics and base-10 mathematics.

- In the binary or base-2 system used by the operating system, 1 gigabyte (GB) is equal to 1,073,741,824 bytes.
- In the base-10 system used by hard disk drive manufacturers, 1 gigabyte (GB) is equal to 1,000,000,000 bytes (rather than the 1,073,741,824 bytes, as listed above).

This discrepancy in reporting drive sizes (base-2 vs. base-10) may lead you to believe that you have a hard disk drive of less than expected capacity if you compare the figure reported by the operating system with the figure reported by your documentation, although the actual hard drive size is identical.

These two mathematical systems produce 2 different numbers but actually the stored space reported by each of them is the same.

If you have noticed this discrepancy, refer to the table below.
BASE-10 BASE-2
36GB    34.3GB
40GB    38.1GB
73GB    69.6GB
80GB    76.3GB
100GB   95.4GB

Comment: Base 2 is usually GiB and base 10 is GB.  OSs usually use base 2/ GiB units, but not always.  Can be confusing.

Comment: Oh thanks for the detailed information....... if that is so, how can i fix it to have a maximum usage??? is there any way that u can acknowledge me as it is much appreciated........

Comment: this is actually a kind of trick of disc producers.
the operating system is already using the disk at maximum width.
You don't need to do anything.

Comment: oh oh ohhh... is it so....